# Derivability of A Function At A Point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}+arcsin \left(\frac {3x}{2x+1}\right)  & x\in[-\frac{1}{5},1] \\
\\
\sqrt{|5x+1|}\ &  x\in R-[-\frac{1}{5},1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

Which are the points of not derivability ?

[image]

Are they  $\frac{-1}{5}$  and 1 ?

[image]

Comment: Does the limit $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exist for $x = \frac{-1}{5}$ and $x=1$?

Comment: at the point $x=-\frac{1}{5}$ the function is continuos, you have to prove (lateral limits): $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$For the point $x=1$ the function is not continuos, therefore the deritive not exist

Comment: i take the derivatives at the point $x=-\frac{1}{5}$ and not are the same, therefore the derivatives not exists in ${-\frac{1}{5},1}$